# WindowsFormsHost control not following the Size set in the constructor

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

I have a windows form user control:

```
partial class LOLControl
{

    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    #region Component Designer generated code


    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(436, 472);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "hey";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "LOLControl";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(518, 509);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }


    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

And it is hosted in a WPF window via WindowsFormHost:

```
<Window x:Class="Production.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Production.WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize">

        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <local:LOLControl x:Name="mapControlWrapper"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
</Window>
```

Note that the size of `LOLControl` is `(518, 509)`--this is the magic figure that I feel satisfied with when I adjust the control size using the Windows Form designer. I want my WPF window to have this size as well.

I would assume that if `LOLControl` size is `(518, 509)`, then at runtime, I will see that `Window` will be of the same size with the `LOLControl` size I see at design time.

I check that when I finish initializing the `LOLControl` at the WPF `Window` constructor, the size of the `LOLControl` is still as per set in the `LOLControl.InitializedComponent` method ( ie: `(518, 509)`).

However, when compile and run, it turns out that the `LOLControl` size is *not* the same as the design time-- the runtime window size is bigger than in design time!

Why?

Comment: Are you complaining about the WPF window's size or the hosted control's size?

Comment: Since it is the runtime behaviour that actually matters, why don't you simply increase the size of the WindowsFormsHost control? You could specify a width and a height for it like you can with any other control.

Comment: @mm8, what do you mean? the issue now is that the width and height in the code that I specify is not respected at runtime. How can increasing the size of windowsformhost control solve the problem?

Comment: <WindowsFormsHost Width="518" Height="509"> ?

Comment: Don't know why, looks like it picks up a fixed size value stored in registry. A work around for this is setting the `SizeToContent` property of the Window.

Comment: @kennyzx, `SizeToContent` sets the Window size to fit the content, not to fit the design time control size